# TeamCity Environment Variables

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, teamcity

How do you access TeamCity environment variables through the post-build event window in visual studio?

What type of evaluation can be done to make sure the build is happening on the build server and not locally where the environment variables do not exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

TeamCity variables are available as any environment variable is in MSBuild, as a property which can be accessed with the $() syntax.

[This list](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Predefined+Properties) defines the default TeamCity variables that are available to your build process.  So teamcity.version is available as the environment variable TEAMCITY_VERSION and available to MSBuild as $(TEAMCITY_VERSION).  (Environment variables are not case sensitive).

So to answer your question, a quick test to see if a build is running on the build server:

```
<Target Condition=" '$(TEAMCITY_VERSION)' != '' " >
    <Message Text="Running on build server!..." />
</Target>
```

Or a real-world example which uses the TeamCity NUnit runner on the build machine and MSBuild Community Tasks if not:

```
<!-- Override the MSBuild Community Tasks NUnit task if building in TeamCity -->
<UsingTask Condition=" '$(teamcity_dotnet_nunitlauncher_msbuild_task)' != '' "
    TaskName="NUnit" AssemblyFile="$(teamcity_dotnet_nunitlauncher_msbuild_task)" />
```

Comment: A link to the most recent version in TeamCity's documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Predefined+Build+Parameters